# why the command script generated for my npm package is different than other package?

Tags: node.js, cygwin, npm, command-line-interface

I published a npm package myself: [makeTimeTable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/maketimetable)

I installed it happily in cygwin:

```
npm install -g maketimetable
```

But when I try to run the command line, an error is thrown:

```
/node_modules/maketimetable/cli.js: No such file or directory
```

Finally I figure out that the command script file(`C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\maketimetable`) generated when installing my package is different than other global command line tools I installed, below is mine:

```
"$basedir/node_modules/maketimetable/cli.js"   "$@"
exit $?
```

other global command line tools' script is like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=`dirname "$0"`

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

So in other tools' script, it will distinguish whether I'm using cygwin, it will treat the path and directory a little differently. But why my package's script is different than those? How can I make npm to generate the same kind of script for my package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `#!/usr/bin/env node` as the first line of your `cli.js`.